# cgo passing struct with a flexible array member error

Tags: c, cgo

the c code:

> struct RangeResult {
>       int bsucc;
>       int size;
>       const char *contents[];  };
>
> extern struct RangeResult get_range(void*, unsigned int key, int
>   limit, unsigned int max_limit);

the go code:

> ret := C.get_range(filesdb, C.uint(1), 100, 1000)     for i := 0; i <
>   int(ret.size); i++ {      fmt.Println("value:",
>   C.GoString(ret.contents[i]))  }

go build error message:

> /gofilesdb.go: In function '_cgo_2e3328a0efbe_Cfunc_get_range':
>   ./gofilesdb.go:86:7: note: the ABI of passing struct with a flexible
>   array member has changed in GCC 4.4

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Someone with the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883439/getting-the-following-warning-the-abi-of-passing-struct-with-a-flexible-array) getting the error because they are trying to pass the struct by value. Same issue?

Comment: I don't know how the C function could possibly work as intended, even in C. The size of a structure with a flexible array member is as though the array is zero length. So if you return such a struct type from a function, or pass it by value or copy it by assignment, the returned struct, function parameter, or result of assignment will have no contents in the flexible array member.